# Batch Export PNG Sequence from Adobe Flash FLA files

Tags: flash, scripting, batch-file, png, export

I found this script online to batch publish fla files, is it possible to change it to export png file sequences to the same directory? Unfortunately Flash only allows a single image to be published, but has the ability to "export movie" as a png sequence

```
var tempDoc=undefined;
if(fl.documents.length==0){
    //xmlPanel need a document, if there is none, create a temp document
    tempDoc=fl.createDocument();
}
xui = fl.getDocumentDOM().xmlPanel(fl.configURI + "Commands/AutoPublishUI.xml");
if(tempDoc){
    //close temp document
    fl.closeDocument(tempDoc);
}
if(xui.dismiss=="accept"){
    var searchSubDir=xui.searchSubDir;
    var onlyUnpublished=xui.onlyUnpublished;
    var folders=xui.paths.split("\r").join("").split("\n").join("");
    var writeFile=xui.writeToFile;
    fl.trace(writeFile);
    folders=folders.split(",");
    //fl.trace(folders);
    for(var i=0;i<folders.length;i++){
        if(folders[i].substr(0,8)!="file:///"){
            folders[i]="file:///"+folders[i].split(":").join("|").split("\\").join("/");
            //fl.trace("format:"+folders[i]);
        }
        if(folders[i].substr(folders[i].length-1,1)!="/"){
            folders[i]=folders[i]+"/";
        }
    }
    exportlist=new Array();
    //fl.trace(folders);
    for(var j=0;j<folders.length;j++){
        checkFolder(folders[j],exportlist,searchSubDir,onlyUnpublished);
    }
    var totaltime=0;
    if(exportlist.length==0){
        alert("No file need to publish.");
    }else{
        //fl.trace(exportlist.join("\n"));
        fl.trace(writeFile);
        if(writeFile=="true"){
            var d=new Date();
            var script="//publish script created at "+d+"\n";
            script+="function formatTime(num){\n";
            script+="   var h=Math.floor(num/3600000);\n";
            script+="   num=num%3600000;\n";
            script+="   var m=Math.floor(num/60000);\n";
            script+="   if(m<10){\n";
            script+="       m=\"0\"+m;\n";
            script+="   }\n";
            script+="   num=num%60000;\n";
            script+="   var s=Math.floor(num/1000);\n";
            script+="   if(s<10){\n";
            script+="       s=\"0\"+s;\n";
            script+="   }\n";
            script+="   num=num%1000;\n";
            script+="   return h+\":\"+m+\":\"+s+\".\"+num;\n";
            script+="}\n";
            script+="function exportswf(id,total,flapath,swfpath){\n";
            script+="   fl.trace(\"[\"+id+\"/\"+total+\"] \"+flapath.substr(flapath.lastIndexOf(\"/\")+1)+\"\t@ \"+flapath.substr(0,flapath.lastIndexOf(\"/\")));\n";
            script+="   var stime=new Date().getTime();\n";
            script+="   var fla=fl.openDocument(flapath,true);\n";
            script+="   if(swfpath==undefined){\n";
            script+="       swfpath=flapath.substr(0,flapath.lastIndexOf(\".\"))+\".swf\";\n";
            script+="   }\n";
            script+="   fla.exportSWF(swfpath,true);\n";
            script+="   fla.close(false);\n";
            script+="   var etime=new Date().getTime();\n";
            script+="   fl.trace(\"Completed in \"+formatTime(etime-stime));\n";
            script+="   return etime-stime;\n";
            script+="}\n";
            script+="var totaltime=0;\n";
            script+="fl.trace(\"Start publishing...\");\n";
            for(var i=0;i<exportlist.length;i++){
                script+="totaltime+=exportswf("+(i+1)+","+exportlist.length+",\""+exportlist[i]+"\");\n";
            }
            script+="fl.trace(\"All done. Total time:\"+formatTime(totaltime));\n";
            var scriptfilename=folders[0]+"publish_script "+d.getFullYear()+"-"+d.getMonth()+"-"+d.getDate()+" "+d.getHours()+"-"+d.getMinutes()+"-"+d.getSeconds()+".jsfl";
            fl.trace("Script saved to:"+scriptfilename);
            //fl.trace(script);
            FLfile.write(scriptfilename,script);
        }else{
            if(prompt(exportlist.length+" files need to publish. Type OK to proceed.","OK")=="OK"){
                fl.trace("Start publishing...");
                for(var i=0;i<exportlist.length;i++){
                    fl.trace("["+(i+1)+"/"+exportlist.length+"] "+exportlist[i].substr(exportlist[i].lastIndexOf("/")+1)+"\t@ "+exportlist[i].substr(0,exportlist[i].lastIndexOf("/"))+"");
                    var t=exportswf(exportlist[i]);
                    fl.trace("Completed in "+formatTime(t));
                    totaltime+=t;
                }
                fl.trace("All done. Total time:"+formatTime(totaltime));
            }
        }
    }
}
function formatTime(num){
    var h=Math.floor(num/3600000);
    num=num%3600000;
    var m=Math.floor(num/60000);
    if(m<10){
        m="0"+m;
    }
    num=num%60000;
    var s=Math.floor(num/1000);
    if(s<10){
        s="0"+s;
    }
    num=num%1000;
    //if(h>0){
        return h+":"+m+":"+s+"."+num;
    //}else if(m>0){
    //  return m+":"+s+"."+num;
    //}else{
    //  return s+"."+num+"s";
    //}
}
function exportswf(flapath,swfpath){
    //return 0;
    var stime=new Date().getTime();
    var fla=fl.openDocument(flapath,true);
    if(swfpath==undefined){
        swfpath=flapath.substr(0,flapath.lastIndexOf("."))+".swf";
    }
    fla.exportSWF(swfpath,true);
    fla.close(false);
    var etime=new Date().getTime();
    return etime-stime;
}
function checkFolder(folder,list,checkSub,checkSwf,pre){
    if(pre==undefined){
        pre="";
    }
    //fl.trace(pre+folder+":"+checkSub+" "+checkSwf);
    var flas=FLfile.listFolder(folder+"*.fla","files");
    for(var i=0;i<flas.length;i++){
        //fl.trace(pre+" "+flas[i]);
        if(checkSwf=="true"){
            var flatime=Number("0x"+FLfile.getModificationDate(folder+flas[i]));
            var swfname=flas[i].substr(0,flas[i].lastIndexOf("."))+".swf";
            var swftime=Number("0x"+FLfile.getModificationDate(folder+swfname));
            //fl.trace(swfname+" "+flatime+" vs "+swftime);
            if(swftime<(flatime-100)){
                list.push(folder+flas[i]);
                fl.trace(pre+flas[i]);
            }
        }else{
            list.push(folder+flas[i]);
            fl.trace(pre+flas[i]);
        }
    }
    if(checkSub=="true"){
        var flds=FLfile.listFolder(folder,"directories");
        for(var i=0;i<flds.length;i++){
            //fl.trace(pre+i+" "+flds[i]+" of "+flds.length);
            checkFolder(folder+flds[i]+"/",list,checkSub,checkSwf,pre+" ");
            //fl.trace(pre+i);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I made a script to batch export PNGs from a Flash file, one per frame in the main timeline: [flash-export](https://github.com/jrrbru/flash-export). I don't know if this solves your particular problem, but I found this question while searching for the answer, so it might help others.